# Multi value CheckedComboBoxcell Should be shown on Datagridview without validation error

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to implement a *Multi Value CheckBox ComboBox* in a `DataGridView`. To some extend it is successful, but when I leave editing the cell validation it is throwing an error.

Here is a snapshot of my source code:
[My source code is here at Google.Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z3OeYZdfEa3ONaM7166TBxUYfMAhLPvB/view?usp=sharing)

Suggestions for improvement are welcome.
screenshot 1
[combobox selection is ok in datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub4GJ.png)

screenshot 2
[validation error when i change focus to other cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkG30.png)

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PresentationControls
{

   public class CheckedComboCell : DataGridViewComboBoxCell   //DataGridViewTextBoxCell            // 
    {
       public CheckBoxComboBox cboxg;


        public CheckedComboCell()
        : base()
        {



        }


        public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object
                initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
        {
            // Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value.
            base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue,dataGridViewCellStyle);


           string ss= initialFormattedValue.ToString();
            ss = ss.Replace(" ", string.Empty);

            List<string> result = ss.Split(',').ToList();

            CheckBoxComboBox chkcb = DataGridView.EditingControl as CheckBoxComboBox;

            cboxg = chkcb;

            CheckBoxComboBoxItemList ccc = chkcb.CheckBoxItems;

            if (chkcb.CheckBoxItems.Count>0)
            foreach(string s in result)
            {

                //    if(s!="")
               // chkcb.CheckBoxItems[s].Checked = true;


                }
            else
            {

            }


        }
        public override Type EditType
        {
            get
            {

                // Return the type of the editing control 
                Type kk = typeof(CheckBoxComboBox);
                return kk;
            }
        }


        // Type of this cell's value.
        private static Type defaultValueType = typeof(System.String);

        public override Type ValueType
        {

            get
            {
                Type valueType = base.ValueType;
                if (valueType != null)
                {
                    return valueType;
                }
                return defaultValueType;
            }
        }




        private string label;

        public string Label
        {
            get
            {
                return label;
            }
            set
            {
                label = value;
            }

        }



        public object list { get; set; }
        public string[] DataSource { 

                set {



                if (cboxg != null)
                    cboxg.DataSource = value;


            }
                     }

        protected override bool SetValue(int rowIndex, object value)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                this.ErrorText = "bbbb";
                bool bb = base.SetValue(rowIndex, value);
                return bb;
            }


            return false;
        }







    }

}
```

Comment: We prefer posted code in the question, not linked to other sites.

Comment: One improvement would be to explain what a `Multi Value CheckBox ComboBox` is and how it would work. Another improvement, as Lars points out… no one is going to download the code from some other web site. You should post “here” what you have if you want the help. I would be glad to help simply because I have not a clue what a `Multi Value CheckBox ComboBox` is.

Comment: Hai   @johng ,I have added code sample and some screenshot

Comment: Hai  @larstech ,I have added code sample and some screenshot

Comment: Unfortunately, important parts are missing; I am guessing it may be pertinent to supply the `CellValidating` event since it is throwing the error. In addition, the `CheckBoxComboBox` class is not supplied in the code. Therefore, it will be difficult to pinpoint what the problem is. Lastly, IMHO… this `CheckedComboCell` looks suspiciously like an extended `CheckedListBox`. I am only noting that when a “control” allows for “multiple” selections… it is no longer considered a “ComboBox” of any kind.